# Passport not redirecting after authorization

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am running into a problem where when I try to login using passport, the page does not redirect. The authorization return `true` (correct username, password).

I'm pretty sure it lies somewhere within my `validPassword` function but i'm not sure exactly.

**Login Route**

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.render('login', {});
});
```

**Login Post**

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

**User Prototype**

```
User.prototype.validPassword = function(username, unhashedPassword) {
  async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
      User.find({ "username" : username }, function (err, data) {
        if(err) return handleError(err);
        callback(null, data);
      });
    },
    function (data, callback) {
      var isGood = passwordHash.verify(unhashedPassword, data[0].password);
      callback(null, isGood);
    }
  ], function (err, result) {
    return result;
  });
};
```

**Local Strategy**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    var unhashedPassword = password;
    var passedUsername = username;
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(passedUsername, unhashedPassword)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

There are no errors being printed out to my console so I'm slightly baffled right now. Is the `isGood` being returned in the wrong format maybe? Any help would be great.

Comment: Is it redirecting to the correct subdomain? (127.0.0.1 or localhost)?

Comment: @PSeUdocode if I'm on 127.0.0.1 it redirects to 127.0.0.1 and same goes for local host. What happens is that you put in your info and hit login the url bar goes from `/login` to `/` back to `/login` all within the same sequence which means something isn't authorizing right. It's giving me a 302 error but my `app.post('/login')` route is obviously there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out my problem. The problem lied within my local strategy and my `validPassword` prototype.

Within my strategy I had a `console.log` saying *error, invalid username* or *error, invalid password*. I also had a `console.log` in my `prototype` printing the evaluation of `passwordHash.verify(unhashedPassword, this.password)`.

When I posted to login the console would print as follows:

```
LOG: valid username (Strategy)
LOG: invalid password (Strategy)
LOG: true (Prototype)
```

following the flow of logic, `LOG: true (prototype)` *should* appear before `LOG: invalid password (Strategy)` but it was appearing after which means there was a problem with sync somewhere.

Well, I fixed the problem by removing about 15 lines of code and now it works like a beaut.

This is what my auth strategy looks like now.

**User.prototype.validPassword**

```
User.prototype.validPassword = function(unhashedPassword) {
  return passwordHash.verify(unhashedPassword, this.password);
};
```

**LocalStrategy**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    var unhashedPassword = password;
    var passedUsername = username;
    process.nextTick(function () {
      User.findOne({ username: passedUsername }, function(err, user) {
        console.log('within local strategy', user);
        if (err) { 
          console.log('Error:', err);
          return done(err); 
        }
        if (!user) {
          console.log('Incorrect username:');
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(unhashedPassword)) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  }
));
```

**POST Login**

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```